# ExceptionNotification not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception-notification

I am using ExceptionNotification. Exception notification used to send me emails when an error occured, but now it doesn't.

I'm getting the following error when an error occurs and the exception notifier would like to send:

```
W, [2015-04-21T15:19:14.464284 #98174]  WARN -- : An error occurred when sending a notification using 'email' notifier. NoMethodError: private method `include' called for #<Class:0x007fe291e11ad8>
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:482:in `method_missing'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:20:in `block in extended'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:19:in `class_eval'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:19:in `extended'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:137:in `extend'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:137:in `block in mailer'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:136:in `tap'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:136:in `mailer'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:157:in `create_email'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier/email_notifier.rb:143:in `call'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb:94:in `fire_notification'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb:39:in `block in notify_exception'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb:38:in `each'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb:38:in `notify_exception'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notification/rack.rb:42:in `rescue in call'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/exception_notification-4.1.0/lib/exception_notification/rack.rb:32:in `call'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
/Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.11.2.286/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:67:in `call'
```

Etc.

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the bug reports in the [GitHub issues for the project](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/issues).  Looks like there's [an open issue about your problem](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/issues/270) occurring on 4.1.0.  Try downgrading to 4.0.1.